# mysql cpanel netbeans remote connection

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, cpanel

hello guys i have seen similar threads concerning my question but couldn't solve my problem. i am trying to remotely connect to the mysql database hosted on cpanel through my netbeans. i have added my ip address as a host to be allowed remote access. the cpanel ip address was given as https:197.211.45.2:2087. the username given as 'root' and the password also given. in my netbeans i try connecting to the database using the stated parameters and the database name but it wouldnt just connect. i have also tried using the default mysql port it still wouldnt work. if there is anything wrong i have done please put me aright. thanks[the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Gum.jpg). i have attached a snapshot. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems that MySQL port is not added in server firewall and due to that you are getting this issues. Please add port 3306 in firewall and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Under cPanel there is usually 'Remote MySQL' tool which allows you to enter the IP addresses that are allowed to connect into the host.

Comment: on the remote cpanel the mysql is hosted as a localhost.

Comment: @DomkatBStephen Can you please explain how you change hosted mysql localhost into ip address. thanks